# Is it possible for a function to owerwrite the input array with a smaller one?

Tags: c++

The task: Create a function that takes a list of numbers as a parameter, and returns a list of numbers where every number in the list occurs only once

As far as I know, functions can't return arrays. But if a function's parameter is an array, it will be automatically a reference parameter, so it will "overwrite" the input array even if it's a void function. Is there any way to overwrite (as reference parameter) the input array with a smaller one?

To be specific: in the code below I would like to overwrite the number[10] array with the newArray[6]

I just started to learn code this week, this is a practice task for me, so I would like to use C++ basics to solve this one, without pointers and more complex stuff. If it's not possible, it's okay too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void selectionSort(int[], int);

void unique(int[], int);

void print(int[], int);

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {

    int numbers[] = {1, 11, 34, 11, 52, 61, 0, 1, 34, 1, 61, 72};
    int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);

    unique(numbers, size);

    return 0;
}

void unique(int arr[], int size) {

    selectionSort(arr, size);
    int newSize = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
            newSize++;
        }
    }

    int newArray[newSize];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
            newArray[index] = arr[i];
            ++index;
        }
    }

    newArray[newSize - 1] = arr[size - 1];
    print(newArray, newSize);
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[min]);
    }
}

void print(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _"so I would like to use C++ basics to solve this one, without pointers and more complex stuff"_ That would be using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw c-style arrays.

Comment: We haven't learned about vectors yet, so I should solve the task with arrays.

Comment: Then there's no way to do that without `new` / `delete` and complex pointer stuff, sorry.

Comment: Okay, I see. It's fine, I just wondered if I could solve this task in other ways. Thank you!

Comment: *If* you could use a vector it would be trivial: `std::vector<int> getUnique(std::vector<int> numbers) { std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()); numbers.erase(std::unique(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()), numbers.end()); return numbers; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid C++:

```
int newArray[newSize];
```

That's VLA, which is C99, only available with gcc.

Instead, do:

```
int* newArray = new int[newSize];
```

Return this:

```
return std::make_pair(newArray, newSize);
```

As you need to return the size as well!! Even if you can overwrite the input array (you can, obviously, depends on your contract, the documentation of your function), you need to return the new size.

But you may want to take a real C++ class.